# MySQL group by intervals in a date range

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by

I am going to be graphing netflow data stored in a MySQL database, and I need an efficient way to get the relevant data points. They records are stored with the date as an int for seconds since epoch. I Would like to be able to something like:

```
Select SUM(bytes) from table where stime > x and stime < Y  
group by (10 second intervals)
```

Is there anyway to do this? or, would it be faster to handle it locally in python? even for a 500K row table?

**EDIT**
My Mistake, the time is stored as an unsigned double instead of an INT. 
I'm currently using `GROUP BY (FLOOR(stime / I))` where I is the desired interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used suggestions from both answers and a coworker. End result is as follows:

```
Select FROM_UNIXTIME(stime), bytes 
from argusTable_2009_10_22 
where stime > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-600)
group by floor(stime /10)
```

I tried the rounding solution as well, but the results were inconsistent.

Chance

Answer (score 4):

You may be able to do this using integer division.  Not sure of the performance.

Let I be your desired interval in seconds.

```
SELECT SUM(bytes), ((stime - X) DIV I) as interval
FROM table
WHERE (stime > X) and (stime < Y)
GROUP BY interval

Example, let X = 1500 and I = 10
stime = 1503 -> (1503 - 1500) DIV 10 = 0 
stime = 1507 -> (1507 - 1500) DIV 10 = 0
stime = 1514 -> (1514 - 1500) DIV 10 = 1
stime = 1523 -> (1523 - 1500) DIV 10 = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the following? Just devide the tyiem column by 10 and round the result down.

```
SELECT    SUM(bytes) 
FROM      table 
WHERE     stime > x 
AND       stime < Y
GROUP BY  ROUND(stime/10, -1)
```

I don't know wether the ROUND() function and grouping with function calls works in MySQL though, the above is T-SQL.

Comment: round is giving me very variable intervals, over a ten minute period I'm getting some intervals as small as 7secs, and some as large as 1 min...

Answer (score 1):

`FLOOR` in group by sometimes fails. it sometimes groups different times as one value for example when you divide the value with 3 but it doesn't do the same when you divide with 4, although the difference between these two values is far bigger than 3 or 4 which it should group as two different groups. Better cast it to unsigned after floor which works like:

```
CAST(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_field)/I) AS UNSIGNED INT)
```

The problem:

Sometimes  `GROUP BY FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_field)/3)` gives less groups compared to `GROUP BY FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_field)/4)` which is mathematically shouldn't be possible.

Comment: It is mathematically very well possible. Say the values are "3" and "4", then divided by 3 both give 1, while divided by 4 they give 0 and 1. So grouping by /4 will give more groups in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sec_to_time(time_to_sec(datefield)- time_to_sec(datefield)%(10)) as intervals,SUM(bytes) 
FROM table
WHERE where stime > x and stime < Y
group by intervals
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this a few time ago, so i created some function (with sql server, but i assume it's nearly the same) :

First I created a scalar function that return me the ID of a date depending on an interval and a date part (minute,hour,day,moth,year):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetIDDate]
(
    @date datetime,
    @part nvarchar(10),
    @intervalle int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @res int
    DECLARE @date_base datetime
    SET @date_base = convert(datetime,'01/01/1970',103)

    set @res = case @part 
                WHEN 'minute' THEN datediff(minute,@date_base,@date)/@intervalle
                WHEN 'hour' THEN datediff(hour,@date_base,@date)/@intervalle
                WHEN 'day' THEN datediff(day,@date_base,@date)/@intervalle
                WHEN 'month' THEN datediff(month,@date_base,@date)/@intervalle
                WHEN 'year' THEN datediff(year,@date_base,@date)/@intervalle
                ELSE datediff(minute,@date_base,@date)/@intervalle END



    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @res

END
```

Then I created a table function that returns me all the id betweend a date range :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTableDate] 
(   
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @start_date datetime, 
    @end_date datetime,
    @interval int,
    @unite varchar(10)
)
RETURNS @res TABLE (StartDate datetime,TxtStartDate nvarchar(50),EndDate datetime,TxtEndDate nvarchar(50),IdDate int)
AS
begin
    declare @current_date datetime 
    declare @end_date_courante datetime
    declare @txt_start_date nvarchar(50)
    declare @txt_end_date nvarchar(50)
    set @current_date = case @unite 
                WHEN 'minute' THEN dateadd(minute, datediff(minute,0,@start_date),0)
                WHEN 'hour' THEN dateadd(hour, datediff(hour,0,@start_date),0)
                WHEN 'day' THEN dateadd(day, datediff(day,0,@start_date),0)
                WHEN 'month' THEN dateadd(month, datediff(month,0,@start_date),0)
                WHEN 'year' THEN dateadd(year, datediff(year,0,dateadd(year,@interval,@start_date)),0)
                ELSE dateadd(minute, datediff(minute,0,@start_date),0) END

    while @current_date < @end_date
    begin
        set @end_date_courante = 
            case @unite 
                WHEN 'minute' THEN dateadd(minute, datediff(minute,0,dateadd(minute,@interval,@current_date)),0)
                WHEN 'hour' THEN dateadd(hour, datediff(hour,0,dateadd(hour,@interval,@current_date)),0)
                WHEN 'day' THEN dateadd(day, datediff(day,0,dateadd(day,@interval,@current_date)),0)
                WHEN 'month' THEN dateadd(month, datediff(month,0,dateadd(month,@interval,@current_date)),0)
                WHEN 'year' THEN dateadd(year, datediff(year,0,dateadd(year,@interval,@current_date)),0)
                ELSE dateadd(minute, datediff(minute,0,dateadd(minute,@interval,@current_date)),0) END
        SET @txt_start_date = case @unite 
                WHEN 'minute' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @current_date, 100)
                WHEN 'hour' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @current_date, 100)
                WHEN 'day' THEN REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), @current_date, 106), ' ', '-')
                WHEN 'month' THEN REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), @current_date, 106), 8), ' ', '-')
                WHEN 'year' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), datepart(year,@current_date))
                ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @current_date, 100) END
        SET @txt_end_date = case @unite 
                WHEN 'minute' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @end_date_courante, 100)
                WHEN 'hour' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @end_date_courante, 100)
                WHEN 'day' THEN REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), @end_date_courante, 106), ' ', '-')
                WHEN 'month' THEN REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), @end_date_courante, 106), 8), ' ', '-')
                WHEN 'year' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), datepart(year,@end_date_courante))
                ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @end_date_courante, 100) END
        INSERT INTO @res (
StartDate,
EndDate,
TxtStartDate,
TxtEndDate,
IdDate) values(
@current_date,
@end_date_courante,
@txt_start_date,
@txt_end_date,
dbo.GetIDDate(@current_date,@unite,@interval)
)
        set @current_date = @end_date_courante

    end
    return
end
```

So  if I want to count all the user added for each interval of 33 minutes :

```
SELECT count(id_user) , timeTable.StartDate
FROM user
INNER JOIn dbo.[GetTableDate]('1970-01-01',datedate(),33,'minute') as timeTable
ON dbo.getIDDate(user.creation_date,'minute',33) = timeTable.IDDate
```

GROUP BY dbo.getIDDate(user.creation_date,'minute',33)
ORDER BY timeTable.StartDate

:)