# Grouping and summarize columns

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

Given the tables below, what is the best approach to (in both server-flavors):

Group all rows within a minute/hour/day and get the maximum column 'CounterC' ?

Example: Between 'now' and 'now' - 1 day, get Max(CounterC) for each hour.
Example2: Between 'now' and 'now' - 30 days, get Max(CounterC) for each day.

Obviously the rows have to be grouped, but how?

MS SQL

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DE0000000D102D1D](
[index] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[TimeStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[CounterA] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[CounterB] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[CounterC] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[CounterD] [bigint] NOT NULL,
)
```

MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE `de0000000d102d1d` (
 `index` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `TimeStamp` datetime NOT NULL,
 `CounterA` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `CounterB` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `CounterC` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `CounterD` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`index`)
)
```

Some example data:

```
index  TimeStamp                CounterA  CounterB  CounterC   CounterD
-----  -----------------------  --------  --------  ---------  --------
1      2011-03-07 14:25:32.000  0         1         347406352  916
2      2011-03-07 14:26:32.000  0         1         347407169  916
3      2011-03-07 14:27:32.000  0         1         347407978  916
4      2011-03-07 14:28:31.000  0         1         347408617  916
5      2011-03-07 14:29:31.000  0         1         347409087  916
6      2011-03-07 14:30:30.000  0         1         347409557  916
7      2011-03-07 14:31:09.000  0         1         347409845  916
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: It is actually Max(CounterC) I want for each interval, not the sum.

Comment: Have you searched this site? See this for one of many examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607143/mysql-group-by-intervals-in-a-date-range

Comment: Of course I've searched this and other sites...I still don't understand how to solve the problem.

Comment: Date/time processing is an area where SQL Server and MySQL have different set of tools. If someone proficient in MySQL posts an excellent solution for that platform and likewise someone other posts an equally great solution for SQL Server, how would you choose between the two posters whose answer to accept? Or are you intending to accept only an answer with solutions for both platforms?

Comment: Yes, I am aware that there are differences. If I get a solution for one or the other, or at least some pointers that helps me find a solution on my own, then that would be the answer I sought. I could probably figure the other one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server

```
-- Last 30 days grouped by day
select dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, D.[TimeStamp]), 0) as [day], 
       max(D.CounterC) as MaxC
from DE0000000D102D1D as D
where D.[TimeStamp] between dateadd(d, -30, getdate()) and getdate()
group by dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, D.[TimeStamp]), 0)

-- Last day grouped by the hour
select dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, D.[TimeStamp]), 0) as [Hour], 
       max(D.CounterC) as MaxC
from DE0000000D102D1D as D
where D.[TimeStamp] between dateadd(d, -1, getdate()) and getdate()
group by dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, D.[TimeStamp]), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, although the first one isn't entirely syntactically correct, it was close enough for me to get it working, see updated Q.

Comment: [How do you add formatting to these comments? Pressing enter submits the comment.]) Actually, it appears the first query doesn't work as expected, it gives multiple results for some days, and also more than 30 days worth of data. I'm looking into why. Example based of first query:     day MaxC
    2011-05-23 00:00:00.000 371630075
    2011-05-24 00:00:00.000 371676854
    2011-05-25 00:00:00.000 371901143
    2011-05-25 00:00:00.000 371954257
    2011-05-26 00:00:00.000 372101948

Comment: As Homer says...D'oh! My copy-paste key didn't work...or something...querie in Mikael Eriksson's answer works as expected in their unmodified form. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

And for MySQL, here're the same queries:

```
-- Last 30 days grouped by day
select date_format( timestamp,'%Y:%m:%d' ) `day`, max(D.CounterC) as MaxC
from `DE0000000D102D1D` as D
where D.`TimeStamp` between timestampadd(day, -30, now()) and now()
group by date_format( timestamp,'%Y:%m:%d' )
order by `day` ASC;

-- Last day grouped by the hour
select date_format( timestamp,'%Y:%m:%d %H' ) as `Hour`, max(D.CounterC) as MaxC
from `DE0000000D102D1D` as D
where D.`TimeStamp` between timestampadd(day, -1, now()) and now()
group by date_format( timestamp,'%Y:%m:%d %H' )
order by `Hour` ASC;
```